Games get PC to max CPU usage
I notice it primarily when starting the MTG Arena client on my desktop:

Possibly as an after effect it also happens on other games I play like Gloomhaven PC. Especially the latter has always been one of my better performing games so I don't know what's happening.
My specs:

I have also had some bluescreens recently, not that frequently. Seemingly out of nowhere.

How can I diagnose what's the cause of this CPU spike and how can I
solve it?

(I checked other questions but haven't found anything that seems related)
Update
I tried Process Explorer as suggested. The results seem very contradicting. GH.exe CPU usage supposedly was at about 50% max when task manager said it's near 100% (and the game is noticeable laggy):


Yes I saw that and have put mtga.exe on GPU.

I also turned untapped gg off and tried again, it again rockets to 100% cpu usage.

Does this answer your question? What is the best way to identify what caused a CPU spike?

@harrymc I am unsure, isn't that to identify what's causing it? It's the mtga client. Though possibly something else is causing that to go max cpu?

Try it and let us know the answer if that's truly the case. Also, try to reduce whatever display parameters that this game has, perhaps FPS limit if it has one.

Whoever voted for close, please state why. This needs to be solved. You're not contributing by silently closing.

@harrymc I tried it, I can't make any sense of it. See updated question. Thanks for the suggestion.

Have you tried re-installing the game?

The CPU would be 50% if you have two cores and the game is using one of them at 100%. Try reduce the game display parameters - it might be trying to use the hardware beyond its capacity.
